# How to split a text file into multiple text files

Tags: python

Here is a text file.

```
 Oh , yeah , we got this puppy .
 This was a good idea .
 Elliot looks a little green .
 No .
```

and contains so many lines.

I want to split this file into two text file like this way using python or other ways being able to use in linux.

`input.txt` :

```
Oh , yeah , we got this puppy .
Elliot looks a little green .
```

`response.txt`:

```
This was a good idea .
No .
```

So, I would like to get two text files; one has odd-numbered line, the other has even-numbered line.
How can I do?

Comment: Can you show your attempt at this please?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
with open("your_file") as f, open("input.txt", "w") as inp, open("output.txt", "w") as out:
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if (i+1)%2 == 0:
            out.write(line)
        else:
            inp.write(line)
```